# lim$_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int _{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos nt\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis

let $f\in C[-\pi,\pi]$
i.e $f$ is continuous over $[-\pi,\pi]$

Evaluate:lim$_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int _{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos(nt)\,\mathrm dt$

I tried to evaluate it using normal integration technique but that yielded nothing.Any hints

Another one is lim $_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int _{-h}^hf(t)\,dt $  How to do this?

Comment: The first one can be found using what is called the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. I would recommend looking that up. For the second one, write $g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\ dt$ and use the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: For 1, first try to calculate $\lim_n \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nt) dt$. Then use the fact that $f$ is bounded since it is continuous on a compact set.

Comment: @Xiao: actually, I think the argument is that continuous and compact imply uniform continuity, not boundedness (if that's a word). If the integral was over $(0,\pi]$ and $f(x)=\cos(1/x)$, you'd still have a continuous and bounded function, but it probably wouldn't work

Comment: @Alex: It would work.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: looks like it would indeed. What would be a good counter-example? If $f$ has bounded variation, we should have $|\hat f(n)| = O(\frac{1}{n})$, so any counter-example should not be BV ($\cos(1/x)$ isn't).

Comment: @Alex: The result is true in much greater generality; e.g., it suffices for $f$ to be Lebesgue integrable, and in particular it would work for every bounded measurable function. So the only bounded counterexamples would be nonmeasurable, very nasty, and not necessarily existing without the axiom of choice.  For such functions, the problem wouldn't even make sense because the integrals wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Alex A quick proof for boundedness, $f$ is uniformly continuous, given $\epsilon = 1$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. for each $x,y\in [-\pi, \pi]$ we have $$|x-y|<\delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |f(x) - f(y)|<1.$$ Cover $[-\pi, \pi]$ with open balls of radius $\delta$, there exists a finite subcover  centered at $x_1,...x_n$, then for each $x\in[-\pi, \pi]$, we have $$|f(x)| \leq \max\{|f(x_1)|,...,|f(x_n)|\} + 1.$$

Comment: @Xiao: I don't follow your reasoning.  $|\int fg|\leq \int|fg|\leq M\int|g|$, but that doesn't help here.  To get the general case, you could start with step functions (in fact start with the characteristic function of a bounded interval), then approximate bounded measurable functions with those.

Comment: You are right, I just realized that too. I need to work with $\chi_{[a,b]}$ and show the general result for $f\in L^1$. I thought there should an easier argument since I didn't want to use Lebesgue integral for the problem without knowing OP's math background.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: actually yes it's obvious since it's true for simple functions. Still makes me wonder why the continuous case requires some heavy artillery (Heine-Cantor), while the $L^1$ case is completely trivial. All the topology is probably hidden in the construction of the integral ...

Comment: @learningmaths: also, consider "accepting" one of the answers (if satisfactory) to be a good MSE citizen

Comment: Have been thinking, isnt it true that if $a_n$  goes to zero, then for each real number $r$, we have $r a_n$ goes to zero as well?

Comment: @AlexH: I don't agree that it is completely trivial for $L^1$.  Why do you find it obvious for simple functions?  If that is clear for you, then you can easily approximate continuous functions with simple functions.  It is easier to show it is true for step functions, and easier to go from step functions to continuous functions (using uniform continuity) than it is to go to from step functions to simple functions.  (Of course this is a subjective statement.)

Comment: @Xiao: That is true, but what relevance does it have to this question exactly?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I meant that, with the machinery of Lebesgue real integrals in place (which is all but trivial), the direction of the proof was obvious. Completely trivial was a poor choice of words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to bring back old memories of my teacher's very good elementary proof ... I'll try to give a sketch and hopefully some intuition for 1. (2. is trivial as per @Jason's comment):

First note that your integral can be written as 
$$\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos(nt)dt = 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=-n}^{n-1} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f(u/n)\cos(u)du = \\ 
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_k (-1)^k \int_0^\pi f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right)\cos(v)dv \tag{1}$$

Now when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $v \mapsto f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right)$ becomes very "flat" over $[0,\pi]$ while over the same interval $\int_0^{\pi} \cos(v)dv = 0$. So intuitively you would like to see something like 
$$\int_0^\pi f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right)\cos(v)dv \sim \int_0^\pi f\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\cos(v)dv =0$$

To get to that, take $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$, it is also uniformly continuous (from the [Heine-Cantor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)), so there is a $\eta = \eta_{\epsilon} > 0$ so that $\lvert x-y \rvert < \eta \implies \lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert < \epsilon$.

Now let's take an integer $n > N_{\epsilon} = \tfrac{\pi}{\epsilon}$. You would have for all $k$'s: 
$$\forall v \in [0,\pi], \left| f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right| < \epsilon$$
and thus (oh what a mouthful of LaTeX ...):

$$ \left| \int_0^\pi f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right)\cos(v)dv \right| =
\left| \int_0^\pi f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right)\cos(v)dv -
\int_0^\pi f\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\cos(v)dv \right| \le \\ 
\int_0^\pi \left| f\left(\frac{v+k\pi}{n}\right) -
f\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right| |\cos(v)|dv \le
\epsilon \pi $$

Now inject that in $(1)$ and you get:
$$ n\ge N_{\epsilon} \implies \left|\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos(nt)dt \right| \le 2\pi\epsilon$$

And you conclude $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int _{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos(nt)dt = 0$$

Now I hope I haven't ridiculed myself with some major mistake...

The good thing with this proof is that you actually see what topological and functional properties are required to get the result:

- the interval $[0,\pi]$ is compact in $\mathbb R$
- $f$ is continuous and thus uniformly continuous
- $\cos$ verifies $\int \phi = 0$ and $\int |\phi| < \pi$ on each interval $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$

It's probably easy to find examples that show that relaxing any of these conditions would void the result.

Comment: Thanks for including the intuition

Answer (score 2):

Nice one Alex H. :) , I have a proof (that is, in terms of topological tools, close to yours) using a different implementation.

I use two results:

-Firstly, if the hypothesis on the function is $f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$ then you get the result with an integration by part on the cos, and deriving the function. Very easy to prove.

-Secondly, I'll use the Weirstrass theorem: there is a sequence of polynomials that uniformly converges $\rightarrow f$. I'll note the sequence $P_k$.

Now: $| \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos(nt)dt - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_k(t)\cos(nt)dt | = |\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(t)-P_k(t))\cos(nt)dt| \leq 2\pi |f-P_k|_{\infty}$

So, for a certain N positive integer, we get:

$ k \geq N: | \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos(nt)dt - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_k(t)\cos(nt)dt | \leq \epsilon $ ;  thanks to the uniform convergence of the ($P_k$)

From the first point we know that : $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_k(t)\cos(nt)dt \rightarrow 0 $ , when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ , since every polynomial is $C^1[-\pi,\pi]$.

Using | |a| - |b| | $\leq |a-b|$ we get : $|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\cos(nt)dt| \leq \epsilon + |\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_k(t)\cos(nt)dt| \leq 2\epsilon $ , for k>N, n > $N_1$ set with the above result.

Hence you get what you wanted

Comment: Actually that was my classroom proof at the beginning of the Fourier series chapter, in the last century. I'm wondering, my proof relies mostly on the Heine-Cantor theorem (so a property of compact sets in generic metric spaces - I think), while yours relies on Stone-Weierstrass, which is a property of Hausdorff spaces. Any idea where the connection is? I forgot most of these real topology constructions

Comment: @Alex H. Yes, you prove the weierstrass theorem using the Heine-Cantor theorem :), that's the essential part in the proof. That's why i said both proofs were close, mine being the usual one I think

Comment: Of course! Thanks for the refresh.