# Show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin (nt) dt \rightarrow 0 , \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \cos (nt) dt \rightarrow 0$

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

For any integrable function $f:  S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ , I need to show that $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin (nt) dt \rightarrow 0$$ $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \cos (nt) dt \rightarrow 0$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Now, here is what I did -

Using the **Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma** , I got $$\hat{f}(n) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{- inx} dx \rightarrow 0 $$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Now breaking $e^{- inx}$ as $\cos(nx) - i\sin(nx)$ , I get
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) (\cos(nx) - i\sin(nx)) dx \rightarrow 0 $$

If $f(x)$ is a real function then the proving is trivial. But I am not able to find a proof if $f$ is complex. 
I have seen [lim$_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int _{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos nt\,dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039233/lim-n-rightarrow-infty-int-pi-pi-ft-cos-nt-dt) but can someone suggest a different methodology from Fourier analysis point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Um, I think you can just break $f$ into real and imaginary parts, and apply Riemann Lebesgue Lemma to each, just as you did for real valued $f$ here?

Comment: Yes, I did $f = \frac{f + \bar{f}}{2} + \frac{f- \bar{f}}{2}$ but I got stuck in calculation and am not able to proceed forward.

Comment: No no, you said you have proved that for a real $f$, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\sin(nt)dt\to0$, right?

Comment: Yes, but if I suppose $f$ is complex then $ \frac{f + \bar{f}}{2}$ is its real part and $\frac{f- \bar{f}}{2}$ is imaginary. right?

Comment: Yeah. Call them $u$ and $v$, and they are both real. $\int f(t)\sin(nt)=\int u(t)\sin (nt)+i\int v(t)\sin(nt)$ Each goes to $0$ by what you showed. So $\int f(t)\sin(nt)$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Why $v =\frac{f- \bar{f}}{2}$ is real?

Comment: $iv$ is real, work with $iv$ instead of $v$. You can push $i$ inside and outside the integral. And inside and outside limits.